# Winter Bash opt-out doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2017

I hate fun, and now I'm being prevented from actively hating fun.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/winter-bash/opt-out leads to a 404 page.

Comment: One does not simply escape ***fun***

Comment: Same happens to me when try to click on "Wear hat". I want my fun!!!

Comment: [The Winter Bash system is very slow at the moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304371/295232).

Comment: It's suffering from seasonal affective disorder.

Comment: No hats for you, instead have witty comments for the next 3 weeks ...

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. Bleak existence in an uncaring reality can continue.

Comment: Give a hat to that man!

Comment: "I hate fun, and now I'm being prevented from actively hating fun." which means you  are not having fun. Problem solved! :P